# stop scrollbar from fading on mac osx 10.7

Tags: css

i am running Chrome 27 on mac osx 10.7 and I want the scrollbar to always appear on a div with `overflow: scroll;` but it keeps on fading away. How would i go about solving this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and if the system (or a user) wants that, you shouldn't override it anyways.